# How to use Windows Authentication through a RESTful Web API that accesses a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I need to design and implement a Website for Intranet that will use Windows Authentication against the domain. This website needs to present some data that is stored in a SQL Server database. The database also uses Windows Authentication. The first thing that needs to be done when the web application starts up is to call some stored procedure that will return the group that the user belongs to and some type of session token that will be required for all subsequent stored procedure calls. for separation of concerns, I was thinking of writing a RESTful Web API that will be the interface to the database and will provide all the POCO classes that will eventually become models for all my views in the MVC web application. The RESTful API must be hosted in a service and when it calls the DB stored procedure, it will do so using the account under which it runs. Therefore, the information related to the current user that initiated the call in the web application is lost. Is there a solution for this? Or am I over-killing the design by introducing the RESTful API for the data access layer? I can't remember now, but I don't believe there's a way to tell the RESTful API to use the Windows credentials coming in from the client. Is Windows Authentication a bad idea when it comes to web applications? In my case it was a client requirement that was meant to simplify the use of the web portal that I need to develop by removing the extra login step that I would normally have for the application authentication.

Comment: I mentioned the first Login SP because theoretically, after that first call, when I have the session token, I don't need Windows Authentication anymore. All subsequent DB calls will have the token and the DB will be happy. So I am trying to say is that I could have the RESTful API without that first call, which could be a direct call from the server into the database. But this approach kind of defeats the whole purpose of having the data layer nicely encapsulated in a RESTful service. There must be a better solution.

Comment: You can get the authenticated user on the apicontroller. The actual method is different for the different web api versions, but it should be easy enough to google. Your stored procedure could then accept the user identifier as a parameter, and do what it needs to do.